# WP7BarcodeManager.LastCaptureResults not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, barcode

I have WP7 page that reads barcodes using the `WP7BarcodeManager.GetReader().decode(...)` function.
After a successful scan I would like to display the scanned barcode on a rectangle (rScanner) this way :

```
private ImageBrush lastScan = new ImageBrush();

...

lastScan.ImageSource = WP7BarcodeManager.LastCaptureResults.BarcodeImage;
rScanner.Fill = lastScan;
```

No image is displayed (and no exception is raised either)